# Fetching data from Strapi. Error on rerender or when navigate back to page

Tags: reactjs, axios, fetch, strapi

Please, help me with my problem?

I am fetching some data from Strapi and display it in the component.
Everything works well on first rerender, but then odd behaviour starts.

First of all - when i navigate to another page and then navigate back to original page - I ALWAYS get error message =

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

When i stay on the same page and then try to refresh it - sometimes it works OK, sometimes I get the same error message as above.

I think it has something to do with fetching and I i guess don't understand some important concept
How can i fix my problem and whats the best way to fetch data from strapi and use it in components?

Here is the code for fetch function

```
const [data2, setdata2] = useState({});
useEffect(() => {
axios
  .get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_HOST}/api/flipcards`)
  .then(({ data }) => setdata2(data))
  .catch((error) => setError2(error))},
  [])
```

and here is the component:

```
<Box sx={data2text}>
    <Typography sx={data2title}>{data2.data[0].attributes.title2}</Typography>
    <Typography>{data2.data[0].attributes.details}</Typography>
  </Box>
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should check if you have something in your answe. like this:

```
{data2?.data.length > 0 ? (
   <Box sx={data2text}>
    <Typography sx={data2title}>{data2.data[0].attributes.title2} 
    </Typography>
    <Typography>{data2.data[0].attributes.details}</Typography>
  </Box>
  ) : null}
```

Comment: tried it. doesnt work when i navigate to another page and then try to navigate back. Same error type = Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

Answer (score 0):

Found solution!
I did added ? everywhere = data2.data[0]?.attributes?.title2

but also declared data like this:

const [data, setdata] = useState({data:[]})  - i think that fixed the issue!

Comment: Please provide proper code formatting